# Bare Metal Assembly/C(++) Programming

Tags: boot, operating-systems, screen, kernel, assembler

I'm trying to make a small os on my Raspberry Pi.

I have good assembly and strong c/c++ knowledges but I need some help.

For my first experiments I worked with Qemu and it's serial output but now I would like to launch it on a real raspberry pi, draw pixels on screen, etc...
I've heard that the GPU OpenGL support was coded in the Raspberry Pi Linux boot loader. I'm not using a "linux" kernel, i'm doing all from scratch, so is it possible to launch my code by replacing the linux kernel by my kernel, do I have to comply to specific requirements (like entry point function name for exemple) for that, and how can I replace the arm vector table and use OpenGL to show something on screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [12 part course](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/) about writing an OS for the Raspberry Pi from scratch. Part 6 is about graphics. I did not see OpenGL described there, but the examples talk about drawing pixels, then lines, and then text. The first lessons describe how to get the Raspberry to load and run your code.

Comment: Whoa! That's exactly what I need, and maybe more! Thanks a lot! :)